# Acer Aspire One 531h Netbook will not boot

Tags: boot, netbook, acer-aspire-one

The disk in my old Acer Aspire One (AO531h) broke the other day, so I replaced it with the same disk from an old Aspire One (D255). I then wrote over this with Ubuntu 18.04. It was the same installer image I used for that laptop on the old disk. After a reboot, the OS would just boot to a screen with a blinking cursor in the top-right.

Now, no matter what disk or OS I try to boot, I get that. I have tried 3 different internal disks to no avail.

I have tried 6 different USB sticks. I have tried Ubuntu 18.04, 16.04, and 14.04. I have tried Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10, and Windows XP installers (the Ubuntu ones I downloaded from [releases.ubuntu.com](https://releases.ubuntu.com), the Windows images I ripped from the install CDs myself on my PC). Nothing is booting. I have reset the BIOS to defaults. Still nothing.

I'd quite like to salvage this old netbook, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe it's not the disk that broke in that computer?

Comment: Well the PC had been giving me warnings for a month or so, then wouldn't boot past the BIOS but would boot a USB until I replaced the disk.

Comment: Well, replacing the disk doesn't work any more...

Comment: I can't really go back to the old disk (I don't think)? What should I do?

Comment: Have a professional check the computer?

Comment: 1. Windows is not an option; 2. Linux is but NOT Ubuntu - the answer below already states the reason (EoL) - so you should find your desktop Linux among the rapidly shrinking list of distros that still support 32-bit. 3. Honestly, although the task is laudable you should set realist expectations. Anything running on an Atom 32-bit CPU was a turd already when new, let alone almost 20 years later, end of story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Acer D250 readily boots from a USB with [Live Ubuntu **32-bit 16.04**](https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/) made using [Rufus](http://rufus.ie/en/). From that, Ubuntu 16.04 can be installed, and then it can be upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 (there is no 32-bit installer for 18.04, AFAIK). If that doesn't work, check BIOS settings (fast boot: Off, Secure Boot: On, etc.). You might remove *all* partitions from the HDD and let the Ubuntu correctly partition the disk and install the OS on it.

Trying to use an OS from one PC on another often fails because drivers on the first machine differ from those required on the second.